# Cloudinary transformation not beign updated

Tags: cloudinary

I have the following case:

1. created a named transformation "my_transfomation", with 200x100 (width x height).
2. asked for the image through its url (which retrieved the image 200x100).
3. deleted "my_transformation"
4. created another transfomation with the same name "my_transfomation", this time 350x220
5. asked for the same image than in step 2, with the same transformation. I get the image 
   with the old width x height (200x100), instead of the new one (350x220)

If I ask for "my_transformation" on another image, I get the correct 350x220 version.

How could I make the transformation to apply to previously fetched images?

Is there some sort of cache that is making me get the old version of the transformation for images I've already asked for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support from cloudinary respond me that trasnformations currently are cached through a CDN for 1 month.

Comment: 1 month?! that's absurd! is this still the case in late 2016?

Comment: same issue here, looks like the only workaround is to save the transformation as  `my_transfomation2` and use the new name